# Trying to get www. and removal of extensions to work on apache?

Tags: html, apache, .htaccess, redirect, web

I've decided to set up a VPS for my website, which runs on Apache 2.

The first thing I want is for my website to load properly when it is typed with the www. subdomain (is www a subdomain technically?).

I don't care whether it removes the www. or whether it simply works with it in the URL, just that it stays consistent. That's not the case, however, because if I type `[1].com`, it redirects to `[2].com`. Cool and good. But if I type `[1].com/index`, it stays at `[1].com/index`. And in both cases the website works perfectly.

However there's another really bizarre problem in which if I type `[1].com/folder/page`, it redirects to `[2].comfolder/page`. It ONLY happens on that one page, on another nearly identical scenario, it works fine. The way I tried setting it up is simple, I set up the DNS settings for my domain so that A with the host www points to my website's IP, and my VirtualHost settings in apache2.conf have ServerAlias `[1].com`. I used to have a .htaccess file with stuff in it to mitigate it, but even after removing it just to test it, nothing changed at all so I left it that way for now.

The second problem is that I want to make it so that if someone types `[1].com/page`, it directs them to `[1].com/page.html`. This was easy enough at first, currently I have the following in my .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

Trust me, that is NOT the only one I tried. And yes, I've tested that the RewriteEngine itself as well as .htaccess files appear to work fine. So far so good, everything works fine, but wait a second. If I have a file located in `[2].com/folder.html`, and I also have a folder called `[2].com/folder/`, then if I type `[2].com/folder` then it tries to send me to the folder index (which is currently forbidden under the current server configuration). I've tried a million different rewrite codes, and all either do not work or have the exact same problem. The worst part is that previously, the code was also horribly inconsistent, for example `[2].com/folder` would send me to `[2].com/folder/`, but if I went to `[2].com/folder2` then it would send me to `[2].com/folder2.html`!

At this point I'm just completely confused. Maybe there's something I'm completely missing here but I've dealt with so much nonsense and lack of progress (as well as trying out millions of solutions, none of which have worked). Anyone have any advice? Feel free to ask me for code snippets, parts in the .conf files, etc. if you feel that they are needed.

PS: [1] is `www.website` and [2] is `website`. Apparently my post looks too much like spam to be posted

Comment: Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Comment: But honestly, your question needs way more, from your side: A) dont ask multiple questions in one question. Instead: B) put down a clear crisp minimal [mcve] C) don't spend many paragraphs explaining what your code does, or "yes i tried so many things". Give us the essential, minimum thing to understand an issue. When in doubt, rather ask 5 different precise questions, instead of stuffing things into such a *hard to read* monolith.